# PngImageList: why Items.Count incorrent?

Tags: delphi, png

If I lock `TPngImageList` (Delphi7 version) using

```
  L.BeginUpdate;

  L.PngImages.Add.PngImage.LoadFromFile(s1); 
  N1:= L.Count;

  L.PngImages.Add.PngImage.LoadFromFile(s2); 
  N2:= L.Count;

  L.EndUpdate;
```

then, seems, I get wrong N1 / N2, because `Count` is incorrent during `Begin/EndUpdate`. How to read count of icons then?

Comment: Delphi 7 has no `TPngImageList`, so you'll need to be precise about what this component is.

Comment: That's because the image list is filled from the `PngImages` collection when you call `EndUpdate` method (by the `CopyPngs` method) and the `Count` property getter reads the count from the image list (which is not yet updated). But you can read the item count of the `PngImages` collection by the `PngImages.Count` property.

Comment: @TLama, good to post as a answer.

Comment: Do you mean _incoherent_ or _incorrect_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments.

That's because the image list is filled from the `PngImages` collection when you call `EndUpdate` method (by the `CopyPngs` method) and the `Count` property getter reads the count from the image list (which is not yet updated). But you can read the item count of the `PngImages` collection by the `PngImages.Count` property.